# Change dynamic title of review page

Tags: magento-1.9, review, page-title, dynamic

I want to change the title of the review page.

Currently it is display as "**Productname | Websitename**".
But I want to change it in "**Reviews of Productname | Websitename**"

How can I achieve that?

Because I cannot change the XML file, because I need to load the title dynamic because of the productname.

Answer (score 11):

There are several methods available to do that. But i will prefer second one.

```
   1 Core block override
   2 Event/Observer
```

So, once you have created your module, you will need to declare the observer in your config.xml:

```
<!-- config xml -->

<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list>
            <observers>
                <productmeta>
                    <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list</method>
                </productmeta>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list>
    </events>
</frontend>

<!-- config xml -->
```

Then your observer would be similar to this...

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * @pram Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function controller_action_layout_render_before_review_product_list(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   //Get product name and website name in variable after that replace with text below
        $title = "Reviews of Productname | Websitename";
       //After adding dynamic values in variables it looks like below..
       //$title = 'Reviews of' . $product->getName() | $websitename;
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setData('title', $title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good works.. :) +1v