# Product and Category name not showing as page title

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, page-title

My page title only show the suffix page title, i need to uncheck the page title in category page and add the page title manually so the page title will show up and for product i need to fill the meta title, i need the category name or product name as page title as default. In system configuration i already set the title prefix to default value and in my head.phtml i use this code to get title:

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() === 'cms') :  ?>
<title><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_title'); ?></title>
<?php else: ?>
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If I understood your question clearly, this answer might help you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71037/change-dynamic-title-of-review-page/71047#71047